# Difference between ng-model and data-ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I am new with the **AngularJs**. Can anyone say the difference between ng-model and data-ng-model?

**With ng-model**

```
First Name  :  <input type="text" ng-model="fname" id="fname">
Second Name :  <input type="text" ng-model="lname" id="lname">
```

**With data-ng-model**

```
First Name  :  <input type="text" data-ng-model="fname" id="fname">
Second Name :  <input type="text" data-ng-model="lname" id="lname">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Best Practice: Prefer using the dash-delimited format (e.g. ng-bind for ngBind). **If you want to use an HTML validating tool, you can instead use the data-prefixed version (e.g. data-ng-bind for ngBind).** The other forms shown above are accepted for legacy reasons but we advise you to avoid them.

Comment: It is confusing to me in your explanation about which is the best practice.. is it just `ng-bind`?

Comment: you can use both, if you want to have HTML5 valid attribute use data-ng-...

Answer (score 72):

while both `ng-model` and `data-ng-model` would work, HTML5 expects any custom attribute to be prefixed by `data-`.

```
<!-- not HTML5 valid -->
<input type="text" ng-model="name">

<!-- HTML5 valid -->
<input type="text" data-ng-model="name">
```

Answer (score 13):

They are the same. Angular strips the `data-` part from the attribute. From [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine which elements match which directives... The normalization process is as follows:
>
> 1. Strip `x-` and `data-` from the front of the element/attributes.
> 2. Convert the `:`, `-`, or `_`-delimited name to `camelCase`.

Answer (score 9):

There is no difference between `ng-model` and `data-ng-model` if you see in terms of AngularJs.

Actually, '**data**' used as prefix to validate **HTML5 validation**. So, it is good practice to use `data-ng-model`, however, you can use `ng-model` as well. There is no problem in that also.

> Both have the same meaning and both have the same output:

**With ng-model**

```
First Name  :  <input type="text" ng-model="fname" id="fname">
Second Name :  <input type="text" ng-model="lname" id="lname">
```

**With data-ng-model**

```
First Name  :  <input type="text" data-ng-model="fname" id="fname">
Second Name :  <input type="text" data-ng-model="lname" id="lname">
```

Answer (score 1):

sylewester's answer is correct and can be read in the AngularJS Directive Documentation found at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

[image: from the AngularJS Directive Documentation]

(this helped me understand sylwester's answer, so i figured it might help others too.)

Answer (score 1):

sylewester's answer is correct and can be read in the AngularJS Directive Documentation found at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive. Below is an excerpt from that page.

AngularJS normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine which elements match which directives. We typically refer to directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g. ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).

The normalization process is as follows:

Strip x- and data- from the front of the element/attributes.
Convert the :, -, or _-delimited name to camelCase.

For example, the following forms are all equivalent and match the ngBind directive:

[image: prefixes]

[image: from the AngularJS Directive Documentation]

(this helped me understand sylwester's answer, so i figured it might help others too.)