# Angular ng-change not calling code. Am I using wrong model

Tags: javascript, angularjs-directive, mean-stack, meanjs, angularjs-ng-change

I am building an app using MEAN.js generators and a tutorial I found online. Here I have a datepicker in one of my Angular views. For now I would like the ng-change directive to be recognized and do something. At the moment when I make a change to the date my test alert shown here does not get called.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label" for="statusdate">Status Date</label>
   <div class="controls">
      <input type="date"  ng-change="alert('something')" data-ng-model="statusDate" id="statusdate" class="form-control">
   </div>
</div>
```

Can somebody help? I am new to Angular.

Also, I read somewhere it may be because I used data-ng-model as opposed to ng-model. Could this be the case? If so then what is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are executing a method that does not exist in the controller.

Try creating it like this:

```
$scope.alert = function(msg) {
    alert(msg);
 };
```

Comment: Looked more like this but yes your suggestion worked: 
$scope.alert = function () {
     alert();
};

Comment: What if I don't want to create a separate function for alert, can I directly display alert from view file? like : 
**ng-change="$window.alert('alert something')" ??**

Answer (score 3):

Ah, the problem is, you don't have the context you think you do.

Almost everywhere in Javascript, the root of all the closures is `window`, which contains `alert()`.

Almost everywhere, but not everywhere.  Not in the context in which that `ng-change()` is evaluated.  You could fix it by, for example, creating a controller that added a value called `alert` to the `$scope`, and pointing it to `window.alert`.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label" for="statusdate">Status Date</label>
   <div class="controls" ng-controller="myController">
      <input type="date"  ng-change="alert('something')" data-ng-model="statusDate" id="statusdate" class="form-control">
   </div>
</div>
```

And then in the Javascript:

```
angular.module("MyApp")
.controller("myController", ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.alert = $window.alert;
}]);
```

**Edit:** you could use just `window` instead of `$window`, because `window` is available here, but that will make your code more difficult to test in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is ng-change is expecting an expression, but you're giving it a function name alert() to display the string 'something', and hence, it doesn't know what to do.

A possible solution to this is to add this on top of your HTML file

```
<script>
  angular.module('Your_App_Name', [])
    .controller('YourControllerName', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
      $scope.alert = function(message) {
          $window.alert(message);
      };
   }]);
</script>
```

Refer to the documentation for more info on how to use ng-change
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

Refer to [difference b/w ng-model and data-ng-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508053/difference-b-w-ng-model-and-data-ng-model) to understand the difference between data-ng-model and ng-model. They should both work fine.

Comment: I would like to point out two problems with your answer.  First, you don't explain _why_ `alert()`, which is otherwise almost universally knows, is unknown here; second, you "wrapped" the alert function for no (obvious) reason.  On the other hand, your use of `$window` is instructive, so I am going to steal it for my answer.  [evil laughter]