# AngularJs ng-change never fired

Tags: angularjs

when I type something in the box, the `h1` text is changed accordingly. so, `ng-model` is working ok.

however, the `alert` function is never fired. why?

```
<html lang="en" ng-app>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-change="alert('name changed')">
  <h1>Hello3, {{name}}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Angular 1.5.5

**Update**
here it is the working version with the comment from @stackdisplay:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
    app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.myfunc = function(text) { window.alert(text); }
    })
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-change="myfunc('name changed')">
  <h1>Hello, {{name}}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

this is working. however, why don't i get a console error if I don't implement `myfunc` (or previously `alert` function)?

and why using `window.alert` as suggested by @think_win_win does not work, if `window` is a global variable (also, without any error in the console)?

Comment: try writing `window.alert('name changed')`. the function will be evaluated against the current $scope and since you probably don't have a $scope.alert function defined nothing happens.

Comment: i tried with `window.alert` but it does not neither. also, i don't get any error message on the chrome developer console.

Comment: that syntax is firing $scope.alert , so if you don't have an actual $scope.alert function, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 3):

As Per [Stackoverflow Post Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31152047/4382487) :

> Almost everywhere in Javascript, the root of all the closures is
>   `window`, which contains `alert()`.
>
> Almost everywhere, but not everywhere.  Not in the context in which
>   that `ng-change()` is evaluated.  You could fix it by, for example,
>   creating a controller that added a value called `alert` to the
>   `$scope`, and pointing it to `window.alert`.
>
> ```
> <div class="form-group">
>    <label class="control-label" for="statusdate">Status Date</label>
>    <div class="controls" ng-controller="myController">
>       <input type="date"  ng-change="alert('something')" data-ng-model="statusDate" id="statusdate" class="form-control">
>    </div>
> </div>
> ```
>
> And then in the Javascript:
>
> ```
> angular.module("MyApp")
> .controller("myController", ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
>   $scope.alert = $window.alert;
> }]);
> ```
>
> **Edit:** you could use just `window` instead of `$window`, because `window` is available here, but that will make your code more
>   difficult to test in the long run.

Comment: it works if defining a controller as you  mention. i've updated the question with this information. however, why don't i get a console error if I don't implement 'local0 alert function?
and why using window.alert as suggested by @think_win_win does not work, if window is a global variable (also, without any error in the console)?