# Angular validation with HTML5 not working

Tags: angularjs, html

I am using AngularJS for data binding and I am trying to validate data using HTML5 validation features. It is not working though. Below given is my code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Ask", "Question", null, FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "myForm", @name = "myForm" }))
{
    <div id="divQuestionTitle">
        <label>Title</label>
        <input name="Title" type="text" ng-model="Title" required />
        {{myForm.Title.$valid}}            
    </div>
    <div id="divQuestionBody">
    </div>
    <div id="divQuestionTags">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tags)
        <ul id="singleFieldTags"></ul>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tags)
    </div>
    <div id="divQuestionSubmit">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Post Your Question" name="submit"/>
    </div>
}
```

It always displays `{{myForm.Title.$valid}}` on the page.
Please let me know where I am making mistake.

Comment: check ng-app attribute. angularjs seems to have not been bootsrapped

Comment: It is loading. I am getting this error in chrome : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLFormElement.l (http://localhost:49910/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js:5:392)
    at a.validator.e (http://localhost:49910/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js:2:3655)

Comment: Can you paste a url where we can test the web page directly?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508053/difference-b-w-ng-model-and-data-ng-model).
In short, `data-ng-model` directive has to be used in place of `ng-model` if validation is required to be performed.